# Using StringBuilder with DataSet to build dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, stringbuilder

I'm using StringBuilder to dynamically contruct a table from a DataSet.  It's in two parts, one to create the labels and their dimensions and column order.  This part I have working already.  What I'm stuck on is how to get the columns that have "values" then append the string to finish building the table.

There are 25 columns but typically the table with only have 17 or so. I also need to filter out the first column. I'm having trouble conceiving how to do this.  This is what I have so far.  All it does is pull out the first value in the DS.  I can change the index number as well but in this case I can't really do that since the number and index of each column is unknown.

```
            DataSet valuesSet = getBlendInfo.GetProcessValues(reqID);

            foreach (DataRow dRow in valuesSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                tblString.Append("<td>");
                tblString.Append(dRow[0].ToString());
                tblString.Append("</td>");
            }
```

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more detail, otherwise it might just be recommended to use one of the ASP.NET UI controls for this.

Comment: I could have used a Gridview for all of this but I'm learning to live without data controls now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DataSet valuesSet = getBlendInfo.GetProcessValues(reqID);
foreach (DataRow dRow in valuesSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    bool firstColumn = true;
    foreach (DataColumn dbColumn in valuesSet.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        if (firstColumn)
            firstColumn = false;
        else
        {
            tblString.Append("<td>");
            tblString.Append(dRow[dbColumn].ToString());
            tblString.Append("</td>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  This works.  Kicking myself for not being able to conceive it.  All I need to do now is how to get it to skip the first column which is the ID field and this is golden.

Comment: A way with DataColumn.Expression possibly?

Comment: @JohnKinane I have modified the code to skip the first column. I don't understand your thought about DataColumn.Expression. What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

you just need to use a nested loop, something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    tblString.Append("<tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        tblString.Append("<td>");
        tblString.Append(row[i].ToString());
        tblString.Append("</td>");
    }

    tblString.Append("</tr>");
}
```

check for `null` before reading from `row[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
//This way you can create a row with the column names
blString.Append("<tr>");

foreach(var col in valuesSet.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    tblString.Append("<td>");
    tblString.Append(col.ToString());
    tblString.Append("</td>");
}

blString.Append("</tr>");
```